# Pytorch problem porting code from mac to windows

Tags: python, windows, macos, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to port my code for training a NN from mac os python 2.7 to python 3.7 windows and I fixed all of my code, my NN trains normally. torch version is 0.4.1

The problem is that when I evaluate the NN python just stops without any error message. It simply stops.

This is the exact line:

```
correct += pred.eq(target.data.view_as(pred)).sum()
```

is there a possibility this function is not supported on windows ? But why there is no message for quitting ?

Comment: *Simply stops*: Hangs or terminates?

Comment: @BoarGules It just terminates as if the script was finished. No errors, nothing.